# How do I set up a staggered difference-in-differences design in R?

Tags: econometrics, time-series, paneldata, difference-in-difference

I have data which looks like this:

```
N = 10

ISIC <- c(111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115)
n_workers <- rnorm(N)
year_month <- c(201801, 201801, 201802, 201801, 201802, 201901, 201902, 201901, 201902)
year <- c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019)
month <- c(01, 01, 02, 01, 02, 01, 02, 01, 02)

df <- data.frame(ISIC, n_workers, year_month, year, month)
```

How do I add leads and lags for the variable `n_workers` based on both `ISIC`, `month` and `year` in this situation? So, the 1 year lead `ISIC == 111` for `201801` should be `ISIC == 111` in `201901`.

Thank you.